# Microsoft Graph Beta - User Update - request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I get the following error when [Updating a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) using [Microsoft Graph Beta](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet#microsoft-graph-beta-net-client-library). Permissions should not be an issue as I'm using the following permissions: `user.readwrite.all`, `directory.readwrite.all`. Also, `HireDate` is of type `DateTimeOffSet` that I'm getting by [converting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.op_implicit?view=netcore-3.1) local `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffSet`. So, that should not be an issue either. **Question**: What could be the cause of the error and how can it be fixed?

**Error**:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Code: BadRequest
Message: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set

Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2020-08-31T13:59:10
    request-id: 4b62576f-6572-414c-b9ef-07ea9a61c101
ClientRequestId: 4b62576f-6572-414c-b9ef-07ea9a61c101
```

**Code**:

```
private async void DataGridUserUpdateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

  User user = (sender as Button).DataContext as User;

  string id = user.UserPrincipalName;

   var user = new User
   {
     Department = "IT",
     DisplayName = "Bob Doe",
     HireDate = new DateTime(2020, 8, 31, 2, 30, 0),
     JobTitle = "IT Manager"
   };

  await graphClient.Users[sId]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

Comment: As of now, we can update the hire date(employee hire date) property through  Graph API 
`Patch` `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userid` `{"employeeHireDate":"2020-01-02T00:00:00Z"}`
Please refer to this issue which is already raised in [Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/296) and [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35395435-bug-unable-to-update-birthday-or-hiredate-using-g)

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity Thanks for providing the relevant links. I have voted on the `UserVoice` as it's an important issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some test, I met the same issue as yours. I test it in code with both client_credential grant flow and username/password grant flow(and add enough permissions) but none of them succeeded. Then I test it in graph explorer but also failed. It seems the property `hireDate` can't be updated success.

For a wordaround, I found another property maybe you can use, you can use `employeeHireDate`. I already test to update this property, it works fine. This property just exists when we use beta graph api and we can't find it neither in [v1.0 user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) nor in [beta user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) document.

To update `employeeHireDate` in code, please refer to the code below:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = new User
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"employeeHireDate", "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
    }
};

await graphClient.Users["userId"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(user);
```

**By the way, you need to pay attention to the properties in beta version because it may be changed in future**.

==================================**Update**==================================

[image]

Comment: could you please point to the link that has `employeeHireDate` explained? I searched online but did not get any result for it.

Comment: Hi @nam As I mentioned in my answer, we can't find the property `employeeHireDate` neither in [v1.0 user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) document nor in [beta user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) document. It just exists when we request the beta graph api(get user) and we can edit it by beta graph api.

Comment: @nam I update my answer with a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Seems that `employeeHireDate` was released in October 2020: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#october-2020

Answer (score 0):

As of now, we can update the hire date(employee hire date) property through  Graph API

**Patch** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userid`

`{"employeeHireDate":"2020-01-02T00:00:00Z"}`

Please refer to this issue which is already raised in [Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/296) and [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35395435-bug-unable-to-update-birthday-or-hiredate-using-g)