# Azure AD Connect Sync to DateTimeOffset

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to fill the azure user attribute `employeeHireDate` which has the type `DateTimeOffset`. I could not find any reference for converting to `DateTimeOffset` in [Azure AD Connect Functions Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-functions-reference). Anyone know how to use AD connect rules editor to fill a `DateTimeOffset` field?

I tried many workarounds without success

1. Direct: expirationTime to employeeHireDate
2. Expression: DateFromNum([accountExpires]) where accountExpires is numeric date
3. FormatDateTime(CDate([extensionAttribute1),"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

Comment: are you trying to set the employeeHireDate in DateTimeOffset  format ? Correct if i am not wrong ?

Comment: Please check this Stack Case it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673297/microsoft-graph-beta-user-update-request-is-currently-not-supported-on-the-t

Comment: I don't have problem with Graph. I could create new users with setting employeeHireDate. My problem is with some users who are synced from onPremises Active Directory using AD Connect tool. since there is no direct mapping to employeeHireDate, I'm creating a rule in AD Connect to map another attribute in Active directory with the attribute employeeHireDate in Azure Active Directory. Since employeeHireDate is DateTimeOffset I could not find any way in AD Connect to convert to this data type.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little late, but I was searching for this answer too, how Azure AD Connect needs the employeeHireDate to be formatted in a special way - it needs it in this format:
20210901234320.0Z - basically normal DateTimeOffset (2014-01-01T00:00:00Z) with some characters missing, the dashes, colons and a period with single character before the Z. So an extensionattribute in AD could contain the hire date in this format, then it is just a straight direct sync from the extension attribute to the employeeHireDate in the MV, to the employeeHireDate in the AZ connector space.